# Cannot load JavaScript and CSS files from assets into an html in a WebView

Tags: java, android, html, webview, assets

My WebView cannot render an html file stored in the `assets` folder which contains scripts src (and also CSS path), like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/emergency.js"></script>
```

It's showing a white screen.
Any ideas how to fix that?

I've read other answers, but it seems none of them suits my case.

Here is my code from MainActivity.java

```
    WebView browser = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    String html = "file:///android_asset/file.html";

    browser.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");


    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false); 
    browser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    browser.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);

    try {
            browser.loadUrl(html);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If files are in the same location, then html files will automatically determine files locations. So use Relative Paths, but not Absolute.

http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/emergency.js"></script>
```

simply do like this inside your HTML file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
```

Because the HTML file knows nothing about your `assets` folder.
But it will easily find the files in the same directory.

---

Skip this line:

```
browser.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

And just use

```
browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.html");
```

Comment: it says about file.html that 
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Obviously, you need to use the same file names as yours. Mine work in **my** case, because I have such files in the assets folder, as long as the html which refers them. Take my code as a **generic** example, but adapt it to **your** specific case.

Comment: I also have all files in the asset folder. but it does not work

Comment: Then in the html you must refer them correctly. `href="your.css"` and `src="your.js"` - don't add any path before the file names.

Comment: I edited my answer - It seems you're not loading the HTML file correctly.

Comment: by the way i deleted browser.loadDataWithBaseURL(... seems useless.

Comment: You said that you deleted a useless line. I confirmed that it is useless.